# python sort within a dictionary key

Tags: python, dictionary

I've created the following dictionary from a file:

```
 D = {'dan': ['fileC'], 'sara': ['fileE', 'fileA', 'fileD'], 'ben': ['fileA', 'fileD', 'fileE'], 'joe': ['fileA', 'fileD', 'fileE'], 'jack': ['fileB']}
```

My script prints to a file:

```
 for key in d:
    print','.join(d[key]) + ':' + key

 output is:
 fileC:dan
 fileE,fileA,fileD:sara
 fileA,fileD,fileE:ben
 fileA,fileD,fielE:joe
 fileB:jack
```

I need to sort the values of each key and print one key that has the same value like this:

```
 Desired_output
 fileC:
 dan
 fileA,fileD,fileE:
 sara
 ben
 joe
 fielB:
 jack
```

I'm not able to figure out how to sort this and get the Desired_output.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  I'm fairly new at python and am trying to figure out how to work with dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
for key in d:
  print (','.join(sorted(d[key])))
  print (key)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make another dictionary with the key-value pair reversed from *D*, and then do the print. Here is an option with *defaultdict*(if the order of the result doesn't matter):

```
from collections import defaultdict
default_D = defaultdict(list)

# make the key-value reversed default dictionary
for k, v in D.items():
    default_D[','.join(sorted(v))].append(k)

# print the result
for k, v in default_D.items():
    print(k + ":")
    for item in v:
        print(item)

#fileA,fileD,fileE:
#ben
#joe
#sara
#fileC:
#dan
#fileB:
#jack
```

Comment: Thank you all.  Psidom's solution works the best as it doesn't repeat the values that are the same.  Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest future proofing your code to use the python 3 print function notation instead of the python 2 print statement like so:

```
from __future__ import print_function
d = {'dan': ['fileC'], 'sara': ['fileE', 'fileA', 'fileD'], 'ben': ['fileA', 'fileD', 'fileE'], 'joe': ['fileA', 'fileD', 'fileE'], 'jack': ['fileB']}
for key,val in d.iteritems():
    val.sort()
    print(','.join(val) + ':\n' + key)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using [dict.setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) and [str.join](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) functions:

```
D = {'dan': ['fileC'], 'sara': ['fileE', 'fileA', 'fileD'], 'ben': ['fileA', 'fileD', 'fileE'], 'joe': ['fileA', 'fileD', 'fileE'], 'jack': ['fileB']}

grouped = {}
for k,v in sorted(D.items()):
    grouped.setdefault(tuple(sorted(v)), []).append(k)  # transforming values to keys
for k,v in grouped.items():
    print(','.join(k) + ':\n' + '\n'.join(v))
```

The output:

```
fileB:
jack
fileC:
dan
fileA,fileD,fileE:
ben
joe
sara
```